# Custom controller in Magento's admin without login?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm trying to overwrite IndexController of Adminhtml, below is the source:

```
class T2_AjaxAdmin_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController
{
    /**
     * Administrator ajax login action
     */
    public function ajaxAction()
    {
        $jsonData = array();

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($jsonData));

        exit();
    }
}
```

My config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <T2_AjaxAdmin before="Mage_Adminhtml">T2_AjaxAdmin_Adminhtml</T2_AjaxAdmin>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

I've just found out, any controllers extend from Adminhtml will redirected to login page first.

What I have to do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to look at `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php` which is likely to restrict a list of 'open action' (without login).

You would have to look around line 51 :

```
$requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
$openActions = array(
    'forgotpassword',
    'resetpassword',
    'resetpasswordpost',
    'logout',
    'refresh' // captcha refresh
);
if (in_array($requestedActionName, $openActions)) {
    $request->setDispatched(true);
}
```

Later in that same file, they also check the param `forwarded`, so based on that param, you may fool Magento and access our Controller without the need to log in.

So I just did a check for you and this work my side :

```
class B_Enoit_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch ()
    {
        Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->setParam ( 'forwarded', true );
        return parent::preDispatch ();
    }



    public function indexAction ()
    {
        die ( 'I am in without login' );
    }

}
```

So you have to know that is just a bypass based on the content of this file `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php`

In depth look :

```
public function actionPreDispatchAdmin($observer)
    {
        // some code I omit for shorten purpose
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $user = $session->getUser();

        $requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
        $openActions = array(
            'forgotpassword',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'logout',
            'refresh' // captcha refresh
        );

        // so this test the current action against the list of open actions, which don't have to redirect to login, as seen above
        if (in_array($requestedActionName, $openActions)) {
            $request->setDispatched(true);
        } else {
            if($user) {
                $user->reload();
            }
            // So after reloading the user, it checks if this admin user really exists
            if (!$user || !$user->getId()) {
                // this below condition test if we come from the login page and if we are currently trying to log in
                if ($request->getPost('login')) {
                    // some code I omit for shorten purpose
                }
                // This test the query param forwarded so it is from reading this line that I created my working example
                if (!$request->getParam('forwarded')) {
                    // some code I omit for shorten purpose
                }
            }
        }

        $session->refreshAcl();
    }
```

It looks like they put it in place in a way to access admin data via json or ajax like you are trying to do, so I think this is the way to go for you.
You have to understand that `Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->setParam ('param','value')` in the `preDispatch` of a controller is like faking to pass it as a query parameter.

And indeed if you try to access a controller like that :

```
class B_Enoit_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        die ( 'I am in without login' );
    }

}
```

via the url http://www.example.com/admin/test/index/forwarded/1/ it will work and it will not redirect you to the login even tough it extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I solve this by extend from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`, but I still want to know how this function `Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('forwarded', true)` work? Could you give me more information?

Comment: @NNToan I did an edit of the answer for more explanation

Comment: You are correct, if you set `forwarded`, login will be bypassed, if not, you will get redirected to admin login _if you are not logged in already_. This is a fixed param as the Observer is testing this specific `forwarded` one.